# How to process a JSON object from $.getJSON with a jQuery Click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am not sure whether this is a silly question... I am trying to sort a JSON array using  jQuery click event. The following is a simplified html code which I thought should work:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>

function results(json) {
// display unsorted results in $('#results')
}

$('#sort').click(function (json) {
// sort and display results in $('#results')
});

var query = some_query;
var json = new Object();
$.getJSON(query, results);

</SCRIPT>

<A href='javascript:void(0)' id='sort'>Sort</A>
<DIV id='results'></DIV>
```

I am getting no response upon clicking the Sort link. When I replace the sort function with alert(json), I get a **json is undefined** error. Am I missing out something here?

Further update:

I have amended the code and this should work. Thanks everyone for your contribution :)

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>

function results(json) {
// display unsorted results in $('#results')
$('#sort').click(function() {sort(json);});
}

function sort(A) {
var B = A.sort(sorting()); // function to sort the array
results(B);
}

var query = some_query;
$.getJSON(query, results); // triggered by listener

</SCRIPT>

<A href='javascript:void(0)' id='sort'>Sort</A>
<DIV id='results'></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a couple of changes:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>

function results(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  // display unsorted results in $('#results')
  var json = data;
}

$('#sort').click(function () {
  var query = some_query;
  $.getJSON(url, query, results);
});

</SCRIPT>

<A href='javascript:void(0)' id='sort'>Sort</A>
<DIV id='results'></DIV>
```

Your `results` function will be called when a successful JSON response is received from the url you send your `$.getJson()` request to.

Comment: Thanks. But my intention is to have different sort options. If not, I would have done it in the database query itself.

Answer (score 0):

In you click handler you are expecting "json" as an argument. So it is looking for it in the argument scope.  You have defined "json" as a global variable, but it will not find it there because you are looking for it as an argument.

So you either need to pass "json" to the handler or you need to remove the argument expectation.

Comment: I have removed the argument expectation and follow IAbstractDownvoteFactor's suggestion. But still no response from sort.

Comment: When say "no response from sort", what do you mean?  You are not showing any code for sort(). I would not expect that code to "show" anything.  Are you watching the GET request in FireBug to see if it is firing off a request?  Do you see the response from that?  It doesn't look like anything is being done with the json variable in the code you have posted

Comment: Yes, there's data from GET request in FireBug. I have tested the sort function within the results function and find it to be displaying the sorted result. As I want to have multiple sort options, I split it out so that it can be handled using the click handler. There's no error coming out from error console and no sorting of the result upon clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look at the reply tomorrow. Good night!

Comment: You are still not showing us the code of what your results() and sort handler functions are actually doing. Isn't that where you have the problem? The GET request is being made, you said you receive a response. Have you confirmed that results() is being called when you click on the link? If so, then what is results() doing? Right now it seems it is only assigning the value of one variable to another.